# Select items in ListView by id

Tags: android

This is my code for the ListView, the thing is that i need to select the elements by id, not by position. 
Can anyone help me out with this, i have tried using position but when i delete a listView a new ListView goes into that position which i don't want!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// The data to show
List<Planet> planetsList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
PlanetAdapter aAdpt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initList();

    // We get the ListView component from the layout
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    // This is a simple adapter that accepts as parameter
    // Context
    // Data list
    // The row layout that is used during the row creation
    // The keys used to retrieve the data
    // The View id used to show the data. The key number and the view id must match
    //aAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, planetsList);
    aAdpt = new PlanetAdapter(planetsList, this);
    lv.setAdapter(aAdpt);

    // React to user clicks on item
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                long id) {



            if (position == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Jello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PhotoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Jello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });

    // we register for the contextmneu
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
}


// We want to create a context Menu when the user long click on an item
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map
    Planet planet =  aAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options for " + planet.getName());
    menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Delete");

}




// This method is called when user selects an Item in the Context menu
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    planetsList.remove(aInfo.position);
    aAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
}


private void initList() {
    // We populate the planets

    planetsList.add(new Planet("Work Gallery", 10));
    planetsList.add(new Planet("Buildings Gallery", 20));
    planetsList.add(new Planet("Miscellaneous", 30));


}


// Handle user click
public void addPlanet(View view) {
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    d.setTitle("Add planet");
    d.setCancelable(true);

    final EditText edit = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlanet);
    Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String planetName = edit.getText().toString();
            MainActivity.this.planetsList.add(new Planet(planetName, 0));
            MainActivity.this.aAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged(); // We notify the data model is changed
            d.dismiss();
        }
    });

    d.show();
}
```

}

Planet.java

```
public class Planet {

private String name;
private Integer distance;
private String descr;
private int index;



public Planet(String name, Integer distance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.distance = distance;
}

public Planet(String name, String descr) {
    this.name = name;
    this.descr = descr;
}

public Planet(String name, Integer distance, String descr, int idImg) {
    this.name = name;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.descr = descr;
    this.index = idImg;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Integer getDistance() {
    return distance;
}
public void setDistance(Integer distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}
public int getIdImg() {
    return index;
}
public void setIdImg(int idImg) {
    this.index = idImg;
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean when you delete a listview a new listview goes into that position

Comment: i have a option to delete a listview

Comment: does Planet contain  the field id ?

Comment: no does not contain id field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you,

1. want to access the the Planet Object by id of that object but not with your position
2. have a id field in your `Plannet` Class

If so,

you can do Something like,

```
if (planetsList.get(position).getId() == 0) {
```

EDIT:

in your `Planet` class,

```
public Planet(String name, Integer distance, Integer index) {
    this.name = name;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.index= index;
}
```

and also have getters and setters for your class variable `index`.

And in your code,

```
    planetsList.add(new Planet("Work Gallery", 10,0));
    planetsList.add(new Planet("Buildings Gallery", 20,1));
    planetsList.add(new Planet("Miscellaneous", 30,2));
```

Comment: what happens if i delete the first row in the listview, will the positions change

Comment: What actually happens is, you delete the Item form the Adapter and notify that the data is changed, using notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter, If you maintain the desired order on your planetsList, it will not change the positions if you delete an element

Comment: ah, that's what i'm looking for how to maintain the order even if i delete

Comment: @bappibazzi Can you explain the desired behavior when you delete a item from the list? Because the List does that for you, when you delete item from a list, still the order is preserved, But the List shrinks and the Item after the deleted item get the deleted items index. If you do not what to do that, Have a index in your Plannet object, Then even if you delete the item, it will preserve the previous index for you to use

Comment: @bappibazzi see my code and let me know if it makes sense?

Comment: i also have a option to add new item into the ListView, but every time it has the value 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89104/discussion-between-bappi-bazzi-and-diyoda).

Comment: @bappibazzi I am glad, did your answer derived from my solution or something else, if something else please add your own answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use method view.setTag() in your Adapter. put id in view. And get it in OnClickListener. For example:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertedView, ViewGroup parent) {
    converterView = createView();
    convertedView.setTag(items.get(position).getId())
}

lv.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener -> int id = (Integer) view.getId());
```